# IE flickers when hovering a revealed element

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Im having the worse time trying to make a markup only solution revealing my social media buttons. I have two placeholder buttons for facebook and twitter, and I want to set it up so when a user hovers over the placeholder, it fades out and the share buttons fade in.

Now, I have it working just fine in all the good browsers, but of course, IE (every version) doesnt like it. While the buttons WILL fade in, any mouse movement causes them to flicker, like IE cant decide if the mouse still on the hovered element or not.

Here is what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/cKKxF/

And the code for anyone who doesnt want to leave stack:

```
   <div class="share-buttons-wrapper">
      <div class="buttons-wrapper">
        <div class="facebook share-button">F</div>
        <div class="twitter share-button">T</div>
        <div class="rendered-buttons">
            <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

.share-buttons-wrapper{
    float:left;
    border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    height:75px;
    width:55px;
    padding-left:20px;
    position:relative;
}


    .share-buttons-wrapper > .buttons-wrapper
    {
        cursor:pointer;

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=196749420435782";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

I am seriously about to lose it over here. How can I make this work?

Also - I also tried jQuery because I was so frustrated but it seems that moving the mouse into the share buttons (which are iframes) broke it. So I guess js seems the contents of the iframe as outside the hovered element? I dunno.

Comment: Which IE versions are causing problems?

Comment: All of them, unfortunately

Comment: Seems like you are over-complicating things, I would start over, doing it all in jsFiddle with no JS or iFrames, you can use css transitions if you want the fade.

Comment: Well, I have to use the js and iframes, because thats what FB and Twitter use to render their share buttons. I beginning to think that IE sees the mouse moving into the iframe as it moving out of the dom element which causes the flicker/breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a this extra script seems to fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/SmEqd/

```
$(".buttons-wrapper").hover(
    function () {
$(".rendered-buttons").css("visibility","visible");
    },
    function () {
$(".rendered-buttons").css("visibility","hidden");
    }
);
```

Js bubbling can be handy

Comment: So there is no markup only way to do this huh? In css you can only traverse down the DOM not up? So Im going to go with my conclusion that the iframe contents are considered outside of the DOM which is freaking IE out.

Thanks!